# SaveAs vs SaveAs2 in the Microsoft Office Word object model

Tags: api, com, ms-word, activex, ms-office

It looks like [SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.saveas.aspx) has gone away in Office 2010 in favor of [SaveAs2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.saveas2.aspx). What is going on here? Are there any important differences between the two? My fix has been to check for SaveAs2 first, and then fall back to SaveAs. Is this reasonable?

Answer (score 22):

It hasn't gone away, you've just got another way to save the document.  Save2() takes an extra argument, CompatibilityMode.  If you don't care about the compatibility mode then just keep using Save().  If you do then check Application.Version to verify that you can call Save2() without getting an exception.

Comment: Yes. It only looks as if it is gone away in Office 2010 as the `SaveAs` method might not appear in IntelliSense in the VBA editor. But that doesn't mean that the method is no longer available.