# Save embedded word document from Excel (2007) VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have created the below code for exporting an embedded Word document in a Excel Sheet to the workbook's path:

```
Private Sub Export()

Dim sh As Shape
Dim objWord As Object 'Word.Document
Dim objOLE As OLEObject

    Set sh = Sheet5.Shapes("Object 1")

    sh.OLEFormat.Activate

    Set objOLE = sh.OLEFormat.Object

    Set objWord = objOLE.Object

    objWord.Application.Visible = False

    objWord.SaveAs2 Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\MyTemplate.docx", FileFormat:= _
    wdFormatDocumentDefault

    objWord.Application.Quit

End Sub
```

It is working perfectly on Excel 2013, but when I tried running it in my office on Excel 2007, it gave me a Run-time error '438' "Object doesn't support this property or method" at the line `objWord.SaveAs2 Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\MyTemplate.docx", FileFormat:=      wdFormatDocumentDefault`

Have tried playing around with defining objWord but with no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one isntead:

```
objWord.SaveAs Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\MyTemplate.docx", FileFormat:= _
    wdFormatDocumentDefault
```

Method [SaveAs2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836084%28v=office.15%29.aspx) was introduced only in word 2010.

Also if you didn't add reference to word library in excel vba, you may want to change word constant `wdFormatDocumentDefault` to its value `16`:

```
objWord.SaveAs Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\MyTemplate.docx", FileFormat:=16
```

Comment: Yup that appears to have done it. Out of curiosity, is there any down side of using `SavaAs` as opposed to `SaveAs2`?

Comment: actually thouse methods almost the same except: `Save2() takes an extra argument, CompatibilityMode.` see this post for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107210/saveas-vs-saveas2-in-the-microsoft-office-word-object-model

Comment: Thanks for the clarifaction! I guess I'll stick to `SaveAs`